# Видео .mp4 воспроизводится почти после полной загрузки

Tags: java, android, видео, ffmpeg

Сжатое видео при помощи андроид воспроизводится почти после полной загрузки видео. moov атомы идут спереди, fast-start делаю с помощью ffmpeg. Вот информация о видео файле:

```
Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 24, ends @ 24
Atom moov @ 24 of size: 41615, ends @ 41639
 Atom mvhd @ 32 of size: 108, ends @ 140
 Atom trak @ 140 of size: 18948, ends @ 19088
     Atom tkhd @ 148 of size: 92, ends @ 240
     Atom mdia @ 240 of size: 18848, ends @ 19088
         Atom mdhd @ 248 of size: 32, ends @ 280
         Atom hdlr @ 280 of size: 44, ends @ 324
         Atom minf @ 324 of size: 18764, ends @ 19088
             Atom vmhd @ 332 of size: 20, ends @ 352
             Atom dinf @ 352 of size: 36, ends @ 388
                 Atom dref @ 360 of size: 28, ends @ 388
             Atom stbl @ 388 of size: 18700, ends @ 19088
                 Atom stsd @ 396 of size: 140, ends @ 536
                     Atom avc1 @ 412 of size: 124, ends @ 536
                         Atom avcC @ 498 of size: 38, ends @ 536
                 Atom stts @ 536 of size: 7448, ends @ 7984
                 Atom stss @ 7984 of size: 40, ends @ 8024
                 Atom stsc @ 8024 of size: 28, ends @ 8052
                 Atom stsz @ 8052 of size: 5520, ends @ 13572
                 Atom stco @ 13572 of size: 5516, ends @ 19088
 Atom trak @ 19088 of size: 22551, ends @ 41639
     Atom tkhd @ 19096 of size: 92, ends @ 19188
     Atom mdia @ 19188 of size: 22451, ends @ 41639
         Atom mdhd @ 19196 of size: 32, ends @ 19228
         Atom hdlr @ 19228 of size: 44, ends @ 19272
         Atom minf @ 19272 of size: 22367, ends @ 41639
             Atom smhd @ 19280 of size: 16, ends @ 19296
             Atom dinf @ 19296 of size: 36, ends @ 19332
                 Atom dref @ 19304 of size: 28, ends @ 19332
             Atom stbl @ 19332 of size: 22307, ends @ 41639
                 Atom stsd @ 19340 of size: 91, ends @ 19431
                     Atom mp4a @ 19356 of size: 75, ends @ 19431
                         Atom esds @ 19392 of size: 39, ends @ 19431
                 Atom stts @ 19431 of size: 32, ends @ 19463
                 Atom stsc @ 19463 of size: 28, ends @ 19491
                 Atom stsz @ 19491 of size: 11076, ends @ 30567
                 Atom stco @ 30567 of size: 11072, ends @ 41639
Atom mdat @ 41639 of size: 7113074, ends @ 7154713
------------------------------------------------------
Total size: 7154713 bytes; 38 atoms total. AtomicParsley version: 0.9.0 (utf16)
Media data: 7113074 bytes; 41639 bytes all other atoms (0.582% atom overhead).
Total free atom space: 0 bytes; 0.000% waste.
```

Ссылка на видео: [Видео](http://anonophoto.tk/video5.mp4)

В чем может быт дело?

Comment: попробуйте mp4box использовать

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как можно исправить проблему с помощью mp4box?

Comment: mp4box -inter 500 your_path.mp4
попробуйте